# Why does this db link chain cause a "looping chain of synonyms" error only within an anonymous block?

Tags: oracle, plsql, dblink

I am in a position which requires I pull data to my primary database through a daisy chained dblink set up similar to what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989970/13796169)

`DBLINK_SERVER2 -> SYNONYM -> DBLINK_SERVER3`

The synonym is set up on server 2 like this:

`CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM "MY_USER"."THE_VIEW" FOR "THE_VIEW"@"DBLINK_SERVER3"`

When I run a simple select statement from server 1, it works fine and pulls back exactly what i'd expect from server 3's view:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM THE_VIEW@DBLINK_SERVER2;`

However, whenever I try to run code in an anonymous block any reference to the dblink will cause a "looping chain of synonyms" error.

```
DECLARE
  testnum VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO testnum FROM THE_VIEW@DBLINK_SERVER2;
END;
/
```

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 22:
PL/SQL: ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

There aren't any synonyms on server 1 that i can see which reference the view or dblink. If i run this same test on server 2 both the simple command and block work fine when i use the synonym. Any idea why the block fails on server 1 but not if i run the same thing outside of the block? Is this some kind of permissions problem?

*** Edit ***

We never determined what was causing this, but the DBA changed it so that we were referencing a view in server 2 instead of a symlink. That resolved our problem.

`CREATE VIEW THE_VIEW AS SELECT * FROM THE_VEW@DBLINK_SERVER3`